# linq More efficient way to get data from a table based on another table?

Tags: c#, linq

```
AlinaDatabaseDataContext db = new AlinaDatabaseDataContext();


public List<FaciliteitenLokaalFixed>
                         GetFaciliteitenVoorArchetype(ArchetypesLokaal archetype)
{
    var faciliteiten = new List<FaciliteitenLokaalFixed>();

    foreach(var faciliteit in db.FaciliteitenFixedPerArchetypes
                   .Where(f => f.Naam_archetype.Equals(archetype.Naam)))
    {
        faciliteiten.Add(db.FaciliteitenLokaalFixeds
                   .Where(f => f.Naam.Equals(faciliteit.Naam_faciliteit)).First());
    }

    return faciliteiten;
}
```

I have a table `FaciliteitenFixed`, a table `ArchetypesLokaal` and a table `FaciliteitenFixedPerArchetype`. Function gets an `Archetype` as parameter, looks up all the names of `FaciliteitenFixed` in the table `FaciliteitenFixedPerArchetype` then gets all the `FaciliteitenFixed` objects and returns them in a list.

I've used a foreach here, and this works. But I feel like there probably is a much simpler way to do this when working with Linq.

Comment: Are you using entity framework or LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subselect in a LINQ query:

```
public List<FaciliteitenLokaalFixed>
                         GetFaciliteitenVoorArchetype(ArchetypesLokaal archetype)
{
    var faciliteitenQry =
        from faciliteit in db.FaciliteitenFixedPerArchetypes
        where faciliteit.Naam_archetype == archetype.Naam
        let faciliteitenLokaals =
            from f in db.FaciliteitenLokaalFixeds
            where f.Naam == faciliteit.Naam_faciliteit
            select f
        select faciliteitenLokaals.First();
    return faciliteitenQry.ToList();
}
```